# C-style static array as a member of a template class - won't compile

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I was practising using C++ templates (sounds way better than "playing around") by coding something that would basically be my own implementation of std::array when I stumbled across an odd compilation failure. I reduced the problem into the following class, which fails to compile on gcc version 4.9.0:

```
template <typename TestType>
class TestClass
{
    TestType[10] data;
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My bad. Using templates made me completely oblivious to my mistake in basic array declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array part of the type should go after the identifier:

```
TestType data[10];
```

Comment: Note to self: No more Java. Forgetting basic stuff, grr.